# aws lambda node package requires python

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy a node Lambda function that uses 3rd party packages. One of the packages has a dependency of Python. Is it possible to include a Python binary in my deployment package?

Edit:
I can run the lambda function locally but when I try to run the function on AWS I get an `invalid ELF header` error for the package in question (`node-expat`).

I've tried spinning up an EC2 instance with the same AMI that Lambda uses, then installing all the node packages in this environment before uploading my deployment package...still no luck.

Comment: Which package is this? Most packages do not really need another language to work.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "Python binary". I have never tried to mix node.js and Python in Lambda at the same time. Review this link for the Lambda runtime environment. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

Comment: So I'm kinda struggling here, I'm not really sure what's going on. The package is `node-expat` and its a dependency of another package I'm using that requires XML parsing.

Comment: did you find any solutions? i'm planning to migrate to aws-lambda and i'm using the same package.